# Continuum: Switching from building the SVN Trunk to a Branch

Tags: svn, maven, continuum

We are working with Apache Continuum as a continuous integration platform and i want Continuum to start building from an SVN Branch instead of the Trunk. Did i just need to change the url in the  tag of the  in the Maven pom.xml ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the update policy for the POM is always (http://continuum.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/user_guides/managing_builddef/index.html). This is the default (and in earlier versions of Continuum, was the only behaviour).

If your update policy is not always, or you are building a non-Maven project, you can edit the SCM URL on the project edit screen.

Comment: Actually, we are using the 1.3.6 version http://continuum.apache.org/docs/1.3.6/user_guides/managing_builddef/builddefGroup.html and i didn't find the Update Policy.

Comment: In 1.3.6, that is the only behaviour, so editing the POM should suffice.